# Is there a way around the yfinance Ticker method returning that I'm not authorized?

Tags: http-status-code-401, yfinance, unauthorized

yfinance.Ticker (version 0.2.22) was working for my well for the past 2 months:

```
    hndl = yf.Ticker(symb)
    info = hndl.info
```

Today it fails immediately - returning:

```
HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/AAGIY?modules=summaryProfile%2CfinancialData%2CquoteType%2CdefaultKeyStatistics%2CassetProfile%2CsummaryDetail&ssl=true
```

Linked page shows:

[image]

I note that this has been a recurrent problem over the years. Is there anticipated to be a solution? Or, better to explore alternative ways of getting market data?

TIA

Comment: I note that this post was "downgraded" shortly after posting. Indeed I did research and other users encountered the problem (specifically in R). Answer seemed to be "cookie" related or to use a different API (V6 vs V10). I guess one could use this if one were using the *pandas_dataloader* approach; however, with **yfinance** the user has limited ability to impact the query that is ultimately sent to Yahoo. I also entered the **yfinance** demo code and it too failed. So it appears that either the **API changed** or **yfinance changed**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading yfinance: pip install --upgrade yfinance

Comment: Indeed problem solved - many thanks. Was working on version 0.2.18 successfully until early July. Latter update to 0.2.22 still did not fix the problem. However, updating to most recent 0.2.26 has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

here for the science, research, and discovery. yfinance must have changed something recently again to hinder us.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).